# How to parametrize an error in Mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, error-handling

I am programming the error handling in a MySQL stored procedure using [SIGNAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html). I want to parametrize the error message to make it more helpful. For example

```
 IF vMyVariable IS NULL THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45006'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = ('Found null variable in iteration' || vId); 
 END IF;
```

I tried to use concat() and didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html
and in particular the section about `simple_value_specification`

Arbitrary expression can not be used when assigning attributes with SET, as in:

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45006' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = <sorry, no arbitrary expressions here>;
```

However, a local variable is a `simple_value_specification`, so the following does work:

```
DECLARE my_message_text VARCHAR(64);
my_message_text := <anything you want>;
SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45006' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = my_message_text;
```